# Applying mean value theorem multiple times

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

Say it is given that $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is twice differentiable and that $|g''(x)| < N $ for some value $N$ on the interval $[a,b]$

How would you show that $|g'(x)| <= |\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}|+N(b-a)$ ?

My intuition is that you would apply the MVT to $g(x)$ once to obtain a value for $g'(x)$, then somehow apply it once more in order to obtain a statement about $g''(x)$, at which point you would somehow leverage the $|g''(x)| < N$ condition to somehow obtain the final statement. But I'm incredibly unsure how you would actually go about doing this, or if this is even plausible. Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by using the mean value theorem to write:
$$\frac{g(b)-g(a)}{b-a}=g'(\xi_1)$$
for some $\xi_1\in(a,b)$. Then apply the mean value theorem to $g'$ in the following way:
$$\frac{g'(\xi_1)-g'(x)}{\xi_1-x}=g''(\xi_2),$$
where $\xi_2$ is between $\xi_1$ and $x$, so that:
$$g'(x)=g'(\xi_1)+g''(\xi_2)(\xi_1-x).$$
It follows that:
$$\begin{align*}
\left|g'(x)\right|&=\left|\frac{g(b)-g(a)}{b-a}+g''(\xi_2)(\xi_1-x)\right| \\
&\leq\left|\frac{g(b)-g(a)}{b-a}\right|+\left|g''(\xi_2)\right|\cdot|\xi_1-x| \\
&\leq\left|\frac{g(b)-g(a)}{b-a}\right|+N(b-a).
\end{align*}$$